# Aggregating columns inside a CASE statement

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a case such that

```
~id ~from ~to ~label ~weight
100  A     B   knows    2
100  A     B   knows    3
100  A     B   knows    4
```

But I want only the weight for maximum Date.
How can I modify the below CASE statement such that only 1 entry is there for an ID.

Query:

```
(
select distinct 
CASE WHEN *some-condition* as "~id" 
,CASE *some-condition* as "~from" 
,CASE *some-condition* as "~to"
,CASE *some-condition* as "~label"
,CASE ??? as "weight"
from 
(select 
dense_rank() over(partition by t.job_id order by start_time desc) rnk,                                 
t.Date,
t.job_id,
t.start_time,
t.end_time,
t.dep_id,
t.table_name
.....
t.region_id,
from Table1 t
    ,Tabel2 J  
where t.JOB_ID=J.JOB_ID
)
where rnk=1
order by JOB_ID,table_name
) 
where "~id" is NOT NULL and "~label" is NOT NULL and "~from" is NOT NULL and "~to" is NOT NULL;
;
```

Table t

```
job_id    Date      table_name .......   dep_id   weight
100     2020-10-20     abc                  1        2
100     2020-10-20     abc                  2        3
100     2020-10-20     abc                  3        4
100     2020-10-20     abc                  4        10
100     2020-10-19     abc                  3        2
```

Output weight in the result should be corresponding to maximum dep_id.

```
~id ~from ~to ~label ~weight
100  A     B   knows    10
```

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some ancient roots, they are very different database products

Comment: Yes I realize that. I am looking for Redshift query

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to come up with a solution since you didn't state how `~id, ~from, ~to, ~label` are calculated. You should be able to achieve your desired output with [window functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_first_value.html), i.e. `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
...
,CASE *some-condition* as "~label"
,FIRST_VALUE(weight)OVER(ORDER BY dep_id desc) "weight"
...
```

You may need to add a `PARTITION BY` clause depending if you want to have the first value overall or depending on some other conditions as well.